# kendo grid delete button doesn't trigger delete function

Tags: javascript, post, kendo-ui

Here is my grid:

```
$("#category-gridview").kendoGrid({
     dataSource: {
         type: "json",
         transport: {
             read: {
                 url: function (options) {
                     return '/Product/GetCategories?id=' + $("#selectedProductId").val() + '&company=' + $("#company-dropdown").val() + '&language=' + $("#country-dropdown").val();
                 },
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST"
             },
             destroy: {
                 url: '/Product/DeleteProductCategory',
                 dataType: "json",
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json"
             },
             parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                 console.log("HÄÄR");
                 console.log(options);
                 if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                     return JSON.stringify({
                         category: options
                     });
                 }
             }
         },
         schema: {
             model: {
                 fields: {
                     id: {
                         type: "string"
                     },
                     name: {
                         type: "string"
                     },
                 }
             }
         },
     },
     columns: [{
         field: "id",
         hidden: true

     }, {
         field: "name",
         title: "Category",
         width: "30px"
     }, {
         command: "destroy",
         title: "&nbsp;",
         width: 15
     }],
     editable: false,
 });
```

somehow the read function works as expected but when i press the delete button i won't even reach my parameter map function. 
When i look in chrome console there is no request sent to my controller.

here is my controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult DeleteProductCategory(CategoryResponse category)
{
    return Json(category);
}
```

Comment: Maybe try removing the type: 'json' (according to the documentation http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-type, that isn't a valid setting for dataSource.type)

Comment: thanks! But that didn't help :(

Comment: Oh, I think you need to return something in the parameterMap function for when the operation is destroy.

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer, but to note that i change your transport and the column setting to match the field using kendo because obviously i can't use yours. Similar to this

```
transport: {
             read: {
                 url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products",
                 dataType: "jsonp"
             },
             destroy: {
                 url: "http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/products/destroy",
                    dataType: "jsonp"
             },
             parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                    if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                        return {models: kendo.stringify(options.models)};
                    }
                }
},
```

- At first glance i notice you use "POST" on read and delete call, actually you don't need them?

> But then you said that you couldn't reach the parametermap, i came to
>   think of

- You set `editable : false`, how can you edit it if you
  set it to false? you should make it to `editable : true`(note: also you can try to set it to false and then you can see the delete function will not work)

> [DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/owupu)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stringifing `{param:value}` Simply stringify value i.e `stringify(options.models)` for parameter `category`

```
parameterMap: function(options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                                    return { category: kendo.stringify(options.models) };
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: Perhaps you should edit your answer to include a description how this answers the question.